# How to upload db on google disk with xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-drive-api, google-drive-picker

I have tried to find something about how to upload db on google drive of user using xamarin and I have found nothing. How can I upload it on google drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the google drive api ,here is a sample for java,you could convert it to C#,refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33610727/10768653.

If you are Xamarin.Forms project,you could refer to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63727718/10768653